# How can i keep a popup div always open, even on page refresh/reload until a user close it using HTML5 local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I use the following code to show/hide a div using jquery `toggle`. I try to find a way so browser can remember the last status of the popup div. What i want is to keep this div always open even on page refresh/reload until a user close it. I think that i have to use html5 web storage and js but i don't know how can i apply it on my code.

Here's the code:

```js
    $(".menu-btn").click(function(event) {
     event.stopPropagation();
    $(".menu-window").toggle();
    });
```

```css
.menu-btn {
background:#0088cc;
color:#fff;
font-size:11px;
padding:8px;
text-align:center;
width:150px;
border-radius:5px;
font-weight:600;
cursor:pointer;
}

.menu-window {
background:#ccc;
width:300px;
margin-top:10px;
padding:40px;
text-align:center;
border-radius:4px;
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-btn">MENU</div>
<div class="menu-window">
I AM A POPUP WINDOW
</div>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hi maybe this could help, i tested it and it done the job

```
  // check if there a key store with state of dialog
  $(document).ready(function(){
      // get the value stored
      var isOpen = sessionStorage.getItem("opened");
      if (isOpen === "yes") {
        // if the last value saved was yes so show the dialog
        $(".menu-window").show();
      }
  });

  $(".menu-btn").click(function(event) {
   event.stopPropagation();
   $(".menu-window").toggle(function() {
     // get the last value saved and inverts the value 
     var isOpen = sessionStorage.getItem("opened");
     if (isOpen && isOpen === "no") {
       sessionStorage.setItem("opened", "yes");
     } else {
       sessionStorage.setItem("opened", "no");
     }
   });
  });
```

Comment: i just noticed that you want a localstorage

Answer (score 1):

You can use localStorage for that

```
jQuery(".menu-btn").click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();

       if (jQuery(".menu-window").is(':visible')) {
        jQuery(".menu-window").hide();
        localStorage.setItem("modalFlag", 'false');
       }
       else
       {
        jQuery(".menu-window").show();
         localStorage.setItem("modalFlag", 'true');
       }


       });

    jQuery(window).on('load',function(){
        if (localStorage.getItem("modalFlag") == 'true') {
            jQuery(".menu-window").show();
        }

        if (localStorage.getItem("modalFlag") == 'false') {
            jQuery(".menu-window").hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: This isn't what i need because the popup window must be closed on first visit. Thanx anyway for your time @Omi kabira

Comment: so you want it to be opened always only when a user has already opened it first.

Comment: Yes exactly Omi!